# How to Self-Host SignalR server in .NET5/6 desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I' m working on a desktop application with .NET 6 and WinUI3. This application keeps tracking data changes in PLC and transfers real time data to my server and dashboard.

My server is cloud based. Using the server as a message hub to transmit the data will cause unnecessary delay and performance occupation. That's why I want to host a signalR server in my desktop application so that it could work as a lightweight web server.

I found [Tutorial: SignalR Self-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host) but it's not for .NET Framework 4.x. Can I still host a SignalR server in my desktop application with Asp.Net Core SignalR?

---

I'm a non-native English speaker. There might be some grammatical mistakes in my description and I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can most probably leverage the background services offered in all net core applications.

[signalr/background-services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/background-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Setting it up, can be as simple as this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<ClockHub>("/hubs/clock");
        });
    }
}
```